# Difficulty understanding some algebra done in a problem

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, exponentiation

The main problem is about computer science, trying to show that $f(x)=e^{x^Tx'}$ is of the form $\exp{\Big( \frac{||x - x'||^2}{2\sigma^2} \Big) }$, so it could be a kernel function. (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45381/is-fx-extx-a-suitable-kernel-to-be-choosen) for more details). In the following paragraph, I don't get how the last line is equal to the previous one.

> Often in ML literature, the Gaussian kernel is defined as
>
> $$K'(x,x') = \exp{\Big( \frac{||x - x'||^2}{2\sigma^2} \Big) }$$
>
> But this is actually the *normalized Gaussian kernel*. A normalized
>   kernel, $K'$, is defined:
>
> $$ K'(x,x') = \frac{K(x,x')}{\sqrt{ K(x,x) K(x',x') } } $$
>
> If we use $K(x,x') = \exp{\Big( \frac{x^Tx'}{\sigma^2 } \Big) }$, we
>   get:
>
> $$ K'(x,x') = \frac{e^{x^Tx'/\sigma^2 }}{ \exp{
> \Big(\frac{||x||^2}{2\sigma^2} \Big)}
> \exp{\Big(\frac{||x'||^2}{2\sigma^2}\Big) } } $$
>
> $$ = \exp{ \Big( -\frac{||x' - x||^2}{2\sigma^2} \Big) }$$

And $\exp{\text{(something)}}$ and $e^{\text{something}}$ equal, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, $\exp a$ is another name for $e^a$. You can get the last equality if you take $\dfrac{\exp a}{\exp b\exp c}=\dfrac{\exp a}{\exp(b+c)}=\exp(a-(b+c))$ and simplify.

Comment: @RahulNarain: Right, thank you. But I still don't understand how to get that Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to go the other way.

$$\begin{align}
\lVert x'-x\rVert^2&=(x'-x)^T(x'-x)\\
&=x'^Tx'-2x^Tx'+x^Tx\\
&=\lVert x'\rVert^2-2x^Tx'+\lVert x\rVert^2\\
\end{align}$$
and you can hopefully see how to get there from here.

$$\exp\left(-\frac{\lVert x'-x\rVert^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)=\exp\left(\frac{-\lVert x'\rVert^2+2x^Tx'-\lVert x\rVert^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)=\cdots$$